# how to set up subversion credentials using the command line on windows

Tags: windows, svn, credentials, command-line-interface

I had to reinstall subversion today on a new machine. I would like to be able to make svn commits without having to give it my credentials each time. I would rather not having to install some svn gui.

How do I do that?

Answer (score -1):

Authenticate once and answer Yes when Subversion client asks you whether you want to cache your credentials. Read [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.serverconfig.netmodel.creds)!

Comment: How do I "authenticate once"? Suppose I don't want to make a commit each time I configure subversion?